# Logout functionality in django

Tags: python, django

All

In django project  if 2 template windows are opened and if logout is triggered in 1 window the other window cookies are not cleared.How to delete the cookies also so that the logout will be triggered.

```
def logout(request):
    //request = redirect('webbie.home.views.loginpage')
    //request.delete_cookie('user_location')
    return auth_logout(request)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In the cookie you should only store a session key. The server then needs to keep track of all session keys and associate expire date/time and user-account with them. For every user that logs in they should be given a new session key, though you may allow multiple logins/user-account. So when you check if the cookie is valid you need to consult your sever DB and see if you have this session key and that it's valid. If you now want to "kill" all active sessions for a user-account when one of them logs out you just need to remove all session keys form your servers session key list.
You should try to not store sensitive data in cookies, a session key is enough and then have the server associate data to this key. Now you have control of the signed in users.
More Django session info on there documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly? You mean if you have to windows open with the same website, and you log out in one window, you are not logged out in the other window? I doubt that.

Of course you are not redirected in the other window to a certain page because you haven't done anything in this specific window. But if you click a link that is only available for logged in users, you should be redirected to a login page.

And no, you cannot detect on client side if a user logged out from another site, at least not without Ajax and some custom checks.

Comment: Redirection to the login page is not happening in the second window it has the login state set.So i taught there might be as issue with the cookies

Comment: Its not happening. you mean if you change page, you're still loggedin ?

If you have an ajax-style app, your're responsible of checking the user status then redirect him if needed.